# Can I configure two-step authentication for: SSH and sudo?

Tags: ssh, sudo

I configured two-step authentication for SSH and it works very well, but now I want to configure when I write a command that requires "sudo" to ask me for the two-step authentication code. I followed some tutorials and included this line in:
"/Etc/pam.d/common-auth": "auth required pam_google_authenticator.so".
now when i connect through ssh it asks me for the verification code, then another code, to enter the second code I have to wait 30 seconds to get another code from the application on the phone and then I can enter.
my question is: can i do the two step authentication to ask me once when i log in via ssh and when i enter sudo command?
I use ubuntu 20 04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks promising:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-use-twofactor-authentication-with-ubuntu-20-04

I didn't test it, though; make sure to set a root password at least temporarily so you don't lock yourself out.

Comment: I tried the method, but I disabled the login by password, I commented the line: @include common auth, from the file /etc/pam.d/sshd, now when I connect via ssh I need keys and phone. Before, I also entered the password.
thank you very much for the answer.